# Namespace with index action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, routes

I have an admin controller located inside /controllers/admin/admin_controller.rb
I also have a pages controller located inside /controllers/admin/pages_controller.rb
In my routes.rb file, I have the following:

```
  map.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.resources :pages
  end
```

When the user goes to localhost:3000/admin, I'd like the user to see a page with a link to `/admin/pages` (Pages CRUD) and to `/` (To go back home). Since I am using a namespace, I cannot have an index action for `/admin`. How would I get this done and still have my controllers located inside my `/controllers/admin` folder (rather than using admin as a `map.resources` component and a `has_many` association to pages). Please note I am only interested in the `show` action of admin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have an index action for */admin*:

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.root :controller => "pages"
end
```